# number of solution of system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Prove or provide a counterexamples: $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix

(1) If there exists a vector $b$ such that $Ax=b$ does not have any solution, then $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions when $n>m$.

(2) If $Ax=0$ has infintely many solutions, then there exists a vector $b$ such that $Ax=b$ does not have any solution when $n<m$

For (1) I think it is true, if $Ax=b$ has no solution implies that $b\in R(A)$, so $rank(A)\leq n-1$, hence $N(A)$ has dimension at least 1, so there exists infinitely many solutions.

How about (2)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (2) consider a system of equations that will have infinite solutions, such as this augmented matrix for $Ax=0$:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\2 & 2 & 0\\3 & 3& 0\end{bmatrix}$

Can you show/prove that if *any* system is **overdetermined** (there are more equations than unknowns) and it happens to have *at least one free variable*, that there exists a vector $b$ for which the overdetermined system doesn't have a solution?

(I believe the statement is true given that the premises are $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions (so at least one free variable) and that $A$ has less columns than rows)